# to have fun "on a journey" vs "in a journey"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

Richard Branson in an interview with *Motivated* magazine was quoted as saying:

> To have fun **in** [my] journey through life and learn from [my] mistakes.

<sub><sub>Source: [PERSONAL MISSION STATEMENTS OF 5 FAMOUS CEOS](http://www.fastcompany.com/3026791/dialed/personal-mission-statements-of-5-famous-ceos-and-why-you-should-write-one-too#5)</sub></sub>

Where [my] is replacing *your* in the original.

For some reason this statement doesn't sound right. Should it be **on** my journey through life?

Comment: Why did you feel the need to replace *your* with *my*?

Comment: Wasn't me - the quote is now using [me] where the original interview used _your_.

Answer (score 1):

Common usage would be *in my ... life*, and *on my journey...*.  I guess, in the heat of the moment, one of the two had to take precedence.  That he said '*in*' suggests that he was thinking of more his life than of the journey, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

*On* and *in* can both work with *journey*, and I get a slightly different feeling from the two phrases.  *In* works better for me in the quote.

I think being *in a journey* emphasizes the experience, vs. the getting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer since I don't know the proper grammatical terms, but that's what downvotes are for...

"My journey through life" is a poetic allusion,  equating life to a journey: something with a start and an end. That makes "in my journey through life" equivalent to "in my life".

If one were taking an actual journey,  then one would say "on my journey".